# Optimizing a jQuery drop-down menu function

Tags: jquery, optimization, drop-down-menu, menu

Here's the function, which I am calling like this: `$(document).ready(function(){ dropdownmenu(); });`

```
function dropdownmenu() {   
    $("#navigation ul li.upper").hover(function(){
        $("ul.submenu", this).show(400);
    },function(){
        $("ul.submenu", this).hide();
    }); 
}
```

How can I optimize this function, specifically preventing animation queuing and making it fire properly on page load? Any other tips would ask be welcome!

Last, but not least, the markup:

```
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li class="upper">
            <a href="#">Example</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub-example</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>...</li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the work has already been done for you.

Check out [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)

If you still want to roll your own then at least check the source on this plugin and also
[Hover with intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)